# Why can't this series be looked as a geometric series?

Tags: geometric-series

Why can't this series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^n}$$ be looked as a Geometric Series with $r=\frac1{n}$?

I am looking for answers other than "$r$ is supposed to be a fixed real number from the definition of geometric series".

Thank you.

Comment: No, in this case $r = \frac{(n - 1)^{n - 1}}{n^n}$ and similarly we can call any raw a Geometric Series.

Comment: @Smylic how did you get such value for $r$?

Comment: So, in short, your question is "why is this thing which does not satisfy the definition of a geometric series [which would require $r$ to be a constant] cannot be said to be a geometric series -- and I am looking for answers other than 'because it does not satisfy the definition of a geometric series'"?

Comment: DMH16, I divided summand by previous one.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes.

Comment: I don't mean to be mean, but the comment above was supposed to highlight the hopeless character of such a question. *It is not a geometric series because it does not satisfy the definition of a geometric series*.

Comment: @DMH16 But that's all there is to it. "Why can't we see the a trapezium as a special case of square?" Well, because it is not a square. And the answer to the (not really) deeper question "Why is there no trick that allows me to work on it as if it were a square?" is: because it is not a square and today you've been unlucky not to find the only case where using a wrong method yields a numerically exact result.

Comment: The ratio between successive terms is not constant. Therefore the series is not geometric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric series with $r=\frac{1}{n}$ and $a=\frac{1}{n}$ would be

$$ \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$$

and

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\ne\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to say, but the answer is "$r$ is supposed to be a fixed real number from the definition of geometric series".

Answer (score 3):

The definition of geometric series is that the ratio of $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ must be a non-zero **constant** real number.

Answer (score 2):

You can call anything anyhow to create chaos, but calling this raw a geometric series doesn't give you any profit, because all formulae concerning true geometric series wouldn't give you right result.